# Odoo 12 : How to generate the number, move_name, reference fields?

Tags: odoo-12

I migrate the module "account-invoice-merge" (code here https://github.com/OCA/account-invoicing/tree/10.0/account_invoice_merge) from Odoo 10 to Odoo 12. It works well but, it doesn't generate the number, move_name and reference fields, but I need those for accountacy and control. Can you help me?
Thank you.

Comment: OMG, those fields don't have value when invoices are in draft states